# Reduce systemd-timesyncd's ntp sync period?

Tags: systemd

Is there any ways to reduce systemd-timesyncd's ntp sync period except periodically reload timesyncd service? It seems that there is no configurable variable in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source code for timesyncd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/timesync/timesyncd-manager.c) shows automatic adjustment of the poll interval, so there is no way to influence its behavior. It was designed to figure out how often to poll NTP servers based on your computer's clock drift.

When timesyncd adjusts your clock, it will do this **very gradually** because time jumping by minutes or hours confuses most applications. On computers without a battery-backed real time clock (eg. Beaglebone), the date is Jan 1st 1970 immediately after boot. Those computers need something like ntpdate to force a time sync at boot, after which timesyncd can keep the time on track with gradual adjustments.

Answer (score 4):

systemd v236 (released on 2017-12-14) adds options to configure ntp poll interval (sync period).

From the [changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/a1b2c92d8290c76a29ccd0887a92ac064e1bb5a1/NEWS#L79):

> systemd-timesyncd's configuration file gained a new option
>   RootDistanceMaxSec= for setting the maximum root distance of servers
>   it'll use, as well as the new options PollIntervalMinSec= and
>   PollIntervalMaxSec= to tweak the minimum and maximum poll interval.

Increase the values for `PollIntervalMinSec` (default = 32) and `PollIntervalMaxSec` (default = 2048).